Nagios check_http returning Cannot make SSL connection error on CentOS 7
I'm running a site on Apache (httpd) on a CentOS 7 host and monitoring it using Nagios on another CentOS 7 host. The configuration in Nagios is:
define service {
       check_command                  check_http_url!/my_class/product/session!-f follow -S
       host_name                      mysite.com
       use                            critical-service
       service_description            My Site Production
       servicegroups                  production-sites
       }

This has been working until recently. Nagios is now reporting the following error:
CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection.

I have run the following and also see the error:
[root@mynagiosserver-01 ~]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H mysite.com -u /my_class/product/session -f follow -S -v
CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection.
SSL initialized

On the Nagios host, mysite.com maps to the Apache host IP address in the /etc/hosts file.
Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this further?

Does curl -vL https://mysite.com/my_class/product/session work?

could it be a firewall?  telnet mysite.com 443 to see if connections fail
